# How to add empty values in a vector, matrix, structure

Tags: vector, structure, cell

I am trying to do some calculations where I divide two vectors. Sometimes I encounter a division by zero, which cannot take place. Instead of attempting this division, I would like to store an empty element in the output.

The question is: how do I do this? Can vectors have empty fields? Can a structure be the solution to my problem or what else should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there must be something in the memory slot. Simply store a NaN or INT_MIN for integer values.

Comment: I had the feeling I had seen somewhere a list of values and then a [] instead of a value. But I do not remember if it was in a field of a structure or  I have simply dreamed of it, because I have not used Matlab in the past 3 years at all.